# expand vue component to fill another parent div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bootstrap card component and I will add an icon in the corner to minimize and close (dismiss) the component. I am able to do this.

What I would like next is an icon that I can click that will expand the card component to fill the viewing area.

The viewing area is a portion of the screen that has an id of "main".

The user would then have the ability to click the icon again and it will revert back to its original size.

I have looked at a javascript function that resizes but this is not supported in all browsers. I would need something that worked in 99% of browsers (IE11, edge, firefox etc)

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality?

Comment: It'd be worth having a go at some code and posting that if you get stuck really. You never know what you might get done by having a go. A good staring point would be to look at `display: flex` and some good flexbox docs: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: so far i have https://codesandbox.io/s/0o27yx6onw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somethig like this:

```html
<template>
  <b-card bg-variant="primary" text-variant="white" class="text-center" :class="{ maximized }" ref="card">
    <div slot="header">
      {{ title }}
      <div class="card-header-actions">
        <b-link class="card-header-action btn-minimize" v-on:click="toggle">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" />
        </b-link>
        <b-link class="pl-2 card-header-action btn-close" v-on:click="maximize">
          <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt" />
        </b-link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <b-collapse id="collapse" v-show="expand" visible>
      <b-card-text>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </b-card-text>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "card",
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.expand = !this.expand;
    },
    maximize() {
      this.$data.maximized = !this.$data.maximized;
      var elem = this.$refs.card;
      if (this.$data.maximized){
        const main = document.getElementById("main");
        const rect = main.getBoundingClientRect();
        elem.style.height = rect.height+"px";
        elem.style.width = rect.width+"px";
        elem.style.top = rect.top+"px";
        elem.style.left = rect.left+"px";
      } else {
        elem.style.height = null;
        elem.style.width = null;       
        elem.style.top = null;
        elem.style.left = null;
      }
      //alert("Maximize the card!");
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      expand: true,
      maximized: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#main {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 300px;
}
.card-header-action {
  color: white;
}
.card-header-actions {
  display: inline;
}
.card.maximized {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
</style>
```

This code set style properties for card element. So, maybe this is not so perfectly solution. I tested it in chrome and Edge. in IE11 codesandbox.io doesnt opened :(